# Como agregar a una solución un proyecto ejecutable C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Tengo un error al momento de iniciar una solución en C#, que me manda el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Establecí como proyecto de inicio los archivos Freshdesk y Freshdesk.Test, pero me sigue marcando el mismo error, estos son mis 2 proyectos con sus respectivas clases que tengo en mi solución 'Freshdesk'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que solución habría para este error?
Si necesitan mas información me lo pueden llegar a comentar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pareciera que tu proyecto Freshdesk es de tipo librería (dll). Necesitas algún tipo de proyecto executable (MsDos, WPF, Web, etc) y referir tu proyecto librería en el proyecto. Además necesitas marcar ese proyecto como tu "proyecto de inicio" (Click derecho sobre el proyecto y marcarlo como proyecto de inicio).

Pudieras hacer eso con tu proyecto Freshdesk.Test, pero en realidad no es que estés ejecutando el proyecto. Este es un proyecto para realidad pruebas unitarias, no para ejecutar. Pero bueno, depende de lo que estés buscando.

Comment: Exactamente el proyecto es de tipo librería (dll) lo que estoy buscando es como llamar o referir mi proyecto librería (Freshdesk) a mi proyecto ejecutable, es como llamar a la API de freshdesk a mi proyecto, tienes algún conocimiento de como hacerlo?

Comment: Necesitas agregar un proyecto ejecutable. "De Consola", "Web", "WPF", etc.. una ves que tengas uno, hace referencia a tu proyecto de librería (En lo que es como un folder de 'Referencias' del tu nuevo proyecto, presiona botón derecho y luego 'agregar referencia', por ultimo de la opción de 'Proyectos' seleccionas tu proyecto de librería.

Comment: se puede crear un proyecto "De Consola", "Web", "WPF", etc. vació? para referenciar a mi proyecto de tipo librería?